# mod_rewrite with 2 vars works, but URL changes

Tags: mod-rewrite, virtual-directory

I got some problem with my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^contact/ index.php?p=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^imprint/ index.php?p=imprint [L]
RewriteRule ^escort-rates/ index.php?p=escort-rates [L]
RewriteRule ^discretion-reliability/ index.php?p=discretion-reliability [L]

RewriteRule ^(escort-model)/(\.*)/$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2 [L]
```

If I call **www.domain.com/contact/** the URL won't change visible, but is internally directed to **index.php?p=contact**, it works with the other 3 ones also.

But if I call **www.domain.com/escort-model/escortname/** the URL changes visible to the visitor.
The correct page is called, but the URL changes to **index.php?p=escort-model&l=escortname**

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be (without the parenthesis):

RewriteRule ^escort-model/(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2 [L]

instead of:

RewriteRule ^(escort-model)/(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2 [L]

Comment: The above may not capture $1.  `RewriteRule ^escort-model/(.*)/$ index.php?p=escort-model&l=$1 [L]`

Comment: I also had this before, didn't work. I treid almost all combinations already. Any other ideas where the problem could be?